# How do I get around the error TypeError: self._form.on is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request, electron

I am using the node js request module to send a post request to a website. After looking at the websites request it is using "Form Data" as a payload. The content type for the page is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". My script is being run on a button click in an electron app. A sample of my code is as follows:

```
let options2 = {
                    method: "POST",
                    uri: site_url,//predefined
                    followAllRedirects: true,
                    headers: {
                        'Origin': checkout_host,//predefined
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                        'Referer': referer//predefined
                        'User-Agent': UA//predefined
                    },
                    formData: {
                        information that site is requesting
                    }
request(options2, (err, resp, body) => }
        *I end up repeating the code for different information here*
       }
```

When running my code this is the error I encounter and it stops immediately:

```
TypeError: self._form.on is not a function
```

Comment: What happens if you set the "Content-Type" header to "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @Partik When I do that, I get the same error.

Comment: Are you using the `request` module in Node? Or on the front-end?

Comment: @Partik the request module in node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the reason that this occurs is that when handling an error, the **request** module uses the `.on` method on a `FormData` object. However this isn't the Browser `FormData`, rather it's pulled from another dependency.

Node can recognize everything just fine, but the Browser has some trouble with it. I'm assuming that since you're using this for and Electron app, that might be the issue.

See this to check if it helps: https://github.com/request/request/issues/1961#issuecomment-233956542

Otherwise, if this is on a front-end, maybe using the `fetch()` can be an alertnative.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

---

The other hacky option is to go into the `request` module (specifically `request.js`) and search for `self._form.on` and comment out that block. But I do not recommend this at all because it's simply bad practice, doesn't really solve the problem, and can cause unexpected side-effects.